# Ropevim error in mac os 10.8.4

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, macvim, rope

I use ropevim perfectly in Ubuntu system,
but i got lots of lots error.
i use homebrew to install macvim and python

and follow the tutorial.
http://wizardmode.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-and-homebrew-vim-importerror-no-module-named-site/

I wander know is the ropevim are very buggy or not practical in mac os system.
because the discussion is not popular?
or is there any better solution in vim for Python on mac os?
Thanks very much...it's annoying me lots of time

```
>>> import rope
>>> import ropevim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ropevim-0.3_rc-py2.7.egg/ropevim.py", line 10, in <module>
    import vim
ImportError: No module named vim
```

and when I put the ropevim.vim in .vim/plugin 
I will got the error when using vim

```
/install/ropehg/ropemode:vim la
Error detected while processing function LoadRope:
line    3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pyt
hon2.7/site-packages/ropevim-0.3_rc-py2.7.egg/ropevim.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pyt
hon2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pyt
hon2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2
.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar stack trace when setting up some vim extensions from this page http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide

I believe the problem comes from incompatibilities between 'macport' and native python libraries, and that the native version of vim tries to pull from both.

I ultimately resolved my problem by using macport to install vim with python27 variant.

```
sudo port install vim  +python27
```

The default configuration of macport's vim is without 'python' enabled.